# How to write a caml query that filters by .pdf or folders?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, caml-query, filter, caml

How can I write a CAML query (for javascript ecma) that filters by only pdf documents or folders in sharepoint 2010?
(this is for document libraries)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this field in your CAML query: File_x0020_Type. Compare it to pdf as a fixed value. For folders you can try ContentTypeId eq 0x0120.

Answer (score 2):

It should look something like this (don't quote me because I haven't tested this):

```
<Where>
    <Or>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Type" />
            <ValueType="Text">pdf</ValueType>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" />
            <ValueType="Text">0x0120</ValueType>
        </Eq>
    </Or>
</Where>
```

I recommend downloading a program like SPCamlQueryHelper to work with this stuff, as it's pretty strict about the syntax.